# Best way to do complex conditional queries with Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I just started to teach myself android, and I'm wondering how to use Room to do complex conditional queries?

This is how I currently use the conditional query:

```kotlin
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [ArticleItemEntity::class])
  fun pagingSourceRawQuery(rawQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): PagingSource<Int, ArticleItemEntity>

  fun pagingSource(query: ArticleQuery): PagingSource<Int, ArticleItemEntity> {
    val bindArgs = buildList<Any> {
      repeat(4) {
        add("%${query.keyword}%")
      }
    }.toTypedArray()
    val workStatement = StringBuilder().apply {
      if (query.source.isNotEmpty()) {
        append("AND work_id IN ${SQLiteQueryBuildHelper.getInStatementQuery(query.source)} ")
      }
    }.toString()
    val authorStatement = StringBuilder().apply {
      if (query.author != null) {
        append("AND author_name = '${query.author}'")
      }
    }.toString()
    val platformStatement = StringBuilder().apply {
      if (query.platform.isNotEmpty()){
        append("AND (")
        query.platform.forEachIndexed { index, p ->
          append("platform = '$p'")
          if (index < query.platform.size - 1) {
            append(" OR ")
          }
        }
        append(")")
      }
    }.toString()
    val tagStatement = StringBuilder().apply {
      query.tag.forEach { t ->
        append("AND tag LIKE $t ")
      }
    }.toString()
    val publishTimeStatement = StringBuilder().apply {
      if (query.publishTime.first != null) {
        append("AND publish_time > ${query.publishTime.first!!.toEpochMilli()} ")
      }
      if (query.publishTime.second != null) {
        append("AND publish_time < ${query.publishTime.second!!.toEpochMilli()} ")
      }
    }.toString()
    val gmtCreate = StringBuilder().apply {
      if (query.gmtCreate.first != null) {
        append("AND gmt_create > ${query.gmtCreate.first!!.toEpochMilli()} ")
      }
      if (query.gmtCreate.second != null) {
        append("AND gmt_create < ${query.gmtCreate.second!!.toEpochMilli()} ")
      }
    }.toString()
    val sql = """
      |SELECT * from t_article_item 
      |WHERE (title LIKE ? OR url LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR origin_title LIKE ?) 
      |${publishTimeStatement} 
      |${gmtCreate} 
      |AND browsed = ${if (query.browsed) 1 else 0} 
      |${workStatement} 
      |${authorStatement} 
      |AND favorite = ${if (query.favorite) 1 else 0} 
      |${platformStatement} 
      |${tagStatement} 
      |ORDER BY ${query.orderBy.fieldName} ${query.order.name}
      |""".trimMargin()
    val sqLiteQuery = SimpleSQLiteQuery(sql, bindArgs)
    logger.debug("sql statement：$sql")
    return pagingSourceRawQuery(sqLiteQuery)
  }
```

I know some `ORM` frameworks for `mysql` database, such as `JPA` and `Mybatis`.

I checked the information about `Room` on the Internet, but I didn't seem to see this function, and I still use native `sql`.

Comment: That's NOT Java. Please don't tag-spam.